# Balancing high voltage and ESD safety for a work bench

Tags: high-voltage, safety, esd, workbench

I own various large stainless steel benches which I'm using to sit heavy equipment (200kg+ per bench). Some of this equipment will need new electronic components i'll have to wire up, such as 120vac motors to various relays and circuit boards. Stainless steel is of course highly conductive so I want to avoid the potential for a live wire to ever make contact with the bench and to also ensure ESD safety working with the circuit boards.

I'm relatively new to working with electronics so need some guidance. To solve the first issue I purchased a class 0 insulating mat typically made for floors and placed it on top of the bench, it offers a working voltage of 1000v. It's essentially a single 2mm layer of highly resistant rubber, unlike ESD safe mats, it does not have a conductive under layer, so I'm not sure how to approach grounding the bench and myself, I know wrist straps and a connection to the ESD safe mat bench can be used for grounding, but again this is not an ESD mat, there is no conductive under layer. I don't want to have to purchase a ESD mat to place over this existing high voltage insulating mat, I just want to figure out how to offer ESD safety for the insulating mat I've already purchased, as it was not cheap.

Is ESD safety possible in this situation? Again all I have at the moment is a high voltage insulating safety mat placed on top of the stainless steel bench, nothing more.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two conductors separated by an insulator you have a capacitor. Charge can build up between the two conductors. There would need to be a path for current to flow to prevent that. There is also the problem of shock hazard. Your insulating mat may keep hit wires from shorting to the bench but could a person touching the bench also touch a wire? You need to make sure that any current flow through a person is severely limited, ESD wrist straps usually use a high value resistor so there’s not a direct connection to ground. GFI on your power circuits could also be helpful.

There is a potential for severe injury or loss of life if you get it wrong. You might want to consult with a professional rather than relying on random people on the internet.

Comment: So specifically are you saying charge would build up in the insulating mat itself? Would it make sense to ground the insulating mat then?

Comment: @srb633 No, it’s an insulator, how would you ground it? And it’s sitting right on the presumably grounded bench, so if it could be grounded it already would be. The equipment on the bench would need to be grounded, but in a way that doesn’t create a danger.

Comment: I'm confused, so I have conductive electronics on top of the bench, on the insulating mat, and then obviously under the bench is stainless steel, you said that two conductors separated by an insulator is a capacitor, so charge would build up "between" the two conductors, and the thing between the two conductors then is the insulating mat, but now you're saying charge won't build up in the insulating mat?

Comment: @srb633 Well, technically… but you’re taking the word between too literally, use across instead. If you put an insulator on a metal bench and then put a metal object on top of the insulator there is the possibility that a difference in potential could develop from the object to the bench.

Comment: Right I see. So in short I should use a standard ESD wrist strap for myself, for the charge built up between the electronics and stainless steel, do I need to ground the bench or mat in some way? Or just leave it as is with just the wrist strap.

Comment: @srb633 try just a wrist strap, that may be enough.